# View saved wifi password Iphone 4S

Tags: wifi, iphone, password

Im new to Iphone.  Love it except that I have forgotten the previous saved wifi password for my iphone 4s.  I needed to delete some apps to make room for more and my friend did a reset.  Now I have no password to re-download what I need.  She also did this to my daughters Alcatel Fierce One Touch phone.  So I'm effectively screwed. Im really not phone savvy and have no idea how to find the password I've had saved for a year.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to view a saved password on your iPhone.

However, if the password is a WPA security key, it should be on the internet router itself. The same goes for most other types of Wi-Fi password. Try finding the router and see if you have a line labeled `WPA` or `Passcode`, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

There is no available applications and any tools to show the password of available Wifi networks that you already connected, if your iPhone is not jailbreak. But we have our own tip. Look at the following tips:

**Find Router iP address > Attempt to login to Router with default user and password > view the Wifi password in router setting.**

- To login to the Router, your need to find it’s ip address first. Open the Settings app and tab “Wi-Fi” settings > Look at targeted the wi-fi router / network name that want to reveal the password> tap on the (i) info button.

[image]

- You then should see Router ip address:

[image]

- Open safari > type the Router ip address > Enter. You then is directed to the Router login panel page.

[image]

**The router model is now revealed. You can attempt to login with default user/password (they normally are admin/admin). However, you can go on google to search the exact default user/password quickly with specific Router Model.**

Hope it helps!